# How to, in Python, execute function corresponding to each letter in a string?

Tags: python, string, function, tkinter, python-3.5

Say, for example, in tkinter, someone created a function corresponding to each of the 26 letters of the English alphabet. Then, he/she wants to be able to take a string provided by the user, make all the uppercase letters lowercase, and then execute the function(s) corresponding to each letter of the string. Here is a **pseudocode** example of what I am talking about:

```
# The functions should draw, on a tkinter canvas, the letter each function corresponds to (a pseudocode example shown below):
a -> draw_a
b -> draw_b
c -> draw_c
d -> draw_d
# So on, so forth...

str = input('Enter a string please: ').lower()
for i in str:
    if i is # a letter:
        # execute function corresponding to current letter in string
    else:
        pass # If current character is not a letter
```

**Is it possible to do this in Python? If so, how would I implement this ability?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the following:

If you have an 'a', call function `draw_a`

In that case you can use:

```
letter='a'
locals()["draw_"+letter]()
```

or, in your case:

```
for i in str:
if i is # a letter:
    locals()["draw_"+i]()
else:
    pass # If current character is not a letter
```

`locals()` is a dict containing all defined functions and some other stuff.

Calling `locals()["draw_a"]` returns the funtion `draw_a` as variable, which you then execute using `()`

Comment: This worked perfectly with me not actually having to create a dictionary. The only change I really had to make was change `locals()` to `globals()`, but other than that, this solution is perfect. Thank you very much! :) I will accept your answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: No prob :) By the way, you should be carefull in case you call a letter that does not have a function. You will get an element not found error, so maybe first check `if "draw_"+i in global().keys():`

Answer (score 3):

Use a dictionary to map letters to functions:

```
def draw_a(): # ...
def draw_b(): # ...

per_letter = {
    'a': draw_a, 'b': draw_b, # ...
}

for char in string:
    if char.isalpha():
        per_letter[char]()
```

Note that the function object is put in the dictionary, they are *not* called, not until we look them up in the dictionary with `per_letter[char]`.

Comment: Thank you good sir! I was actually trying this before with a list, but little did I know, this method only works with a dictionary object! Well, anyways, thank you again! :)

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Note that you can only mark *one* answer at a time as accepted. I think you maybe tried to accept all answers here, but that moves the marker. :-) Pick the one that you feel helped you the most! If you feel both answers helped you equally and you can't choose, not picking either is a valid choice too. :-)